Reproduce Knuth's circle and triangle examples
I have been trying to reproduce these examples from Knuth's book Digital Typography:

So far this is the closest I have come:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{shapepar}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hyphenation{iso-peri-met-ric}

\shapepar[6.5cm]{\circleshape}
The area of a circle is a mean proportional between any two regular and similar polygons of which one circumscribes it and the other is isoperimetric with it. In addition, the area of the circle is less than that of any circumscribed polygon and greater than that of any isoperimetric polygon. And further, of these circumscribed polygons, the one that has the greater number of sides has a smaller area than the one that has a lesser number; but, on the other hand, the isoperimetric polygon that has the greater number of sides is the larger.

I turn, in the following treatises, to various uses of those triangles whose generator is unity. But I leave out many more than I include; it is extraordinary how fertile in properties this triangle is. Everyone can try his hand.

\end{document}

How can I exactly reproduce Knuth's examples?

The source of both of those examples is available in the texbook.

If you want to precisely reproduce Knuth's results, you likely don't want to use LaTeX but plain.

The source of both of those examples is available in the texbook
The TeXBook example puts the citation in the circle, rather than under it, but should show the basic idea. As this is from the texbook it's plain tex but would work in latex if you use (say_ \tiny rather than \fiverm

\newdimen\varunit
\varunit=0.989pt % getting ready to make circular insert

\begingroup
% \varunit=1.078pt was used with amr5: it had more letterspacing

\baselineskip6\varunit
\parfillskip0pt
\parshape 19
-18.25\varunit 36.50\varunit
-30.74\varunit 61.48\varunit
-38.54\varunit 77.07\varunit
-44.19\varunit 88.39\varunit
-48.47\varunit 96.93\varunit
-51.70\varunit 103.40\varunit
-54.08\varunit 108.17\varunit
-55.72\varunit 111.45\varunit
-56.68\varunit 113.37\varunit
-57.00\varunit 114.00\varunit
-56.68\varunit 113.37\varunit
-55.72\varunit 111.45\varunit
-54.08\varunit 108.17\varunit
-51.70\varunit 103.40\varunit
-48.47\varunit 96.93\varunit
-44.19\varunit 88.39\varunit
-38.54\varunit 77.07\varunit
-30.74\varunit 61.48\varunit
-18.25\varunit 36.50\varunit
\fiverm
\frenchspacing
\noindent
\hbadness 6000
\tolerance 9999
\pretolerance 0
\hyphenation{iso-peri-met-ric}
The area of a circle is a mean proportional
between any two regular and similar polygons of which one
circumscribes it and the other is isoperimetric with it.
In addition, the area of the circle is less than that of any
circumscribed polygon and greater than that of any
isoperimetric polygon. And further, of these
circumscribed polygons, the one that has the greater number of sides
has a smaller area than the one that has a lesser number;
but, on the other hand, the isoperimetric polygon that
has the greater number of sides is the larger.
\hbox to 36.50\varunit{\hss[Galileo,\thinspace1638]\hss}


\endgroup

\bigskip

\newdimen\x
\x=22.6pt
\begingroup

\setbox1=\hbox{I}
\setbox0=\vbox{\parshape=11 -0\x0\x -1\x2\x -2\x4\x -3\x6\x
   -4\x8\x -5\x10\x -6\x12\x -7\x14\x -8\x16\x -9\x18\x -10\x20\x
  \ifdim \x>2em \rightskip=-\wd1
  \else \frenchspacing \rightskip=-\wd1 plus1pt minus1pt
   \leftskip=0pt plus 1pt minus1pt \fi
 \parfillskip=0pt \tolerance=1000 \noindent
I turn, in the following treatises, to various uses of those
    triangles whose generator is unity. But I leave out many more
    than I include; it is extraordinary how fertile in properties
    this triangle is. Everyone can try his hand.}
\centerline{\hbox to \wd1{\box0\hss}}
\rightline{---Blaise Pascal,\thinspace1654}
\endgroup

\bye




Thanks! This perfectly answers the second half of my question, which is how to exactly reproduce the triangle example from Digital Typography. But it doesn't answer the first half of my question, which is how to exactly reproduce the circle example from Digital Typography. That circle example has a different set of linebreaks and a different font size from the version in Digital Typography.

@BasilCrow but that's just an excersise for the reader,as I don't think that exact source is avaialable. the code here gives a circular parshape. so all you need to do is take the [Galileo citation out of the text as you show it out of the circle then just adjust the font size to get the same line breaks, there is no new technical issue.

Thanks David! As originally asked ("How can I exactly reproduce Knuth's examples?"), the purpose of this question is to solve this exercise for the reader, as I was unable to solve it myself.

Well this does the difficult bit of setting a circle shape, but no problem if you accept a different answer. I fobtvwantvyo change the code here as the point of this answer is to quote the texbook

You can use shapepar package.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\begin{document}
\shapepar[8.095cm]{\circleshape}
The area of a circle is a mean proportional between any two regular 
and similar polygons of which one circumscribes it and the other is 
isoperimetric with it. In addition, the area of the circle is less 
than that of any circumscribed polygon and greater than that of any 
isoperimetric polygon. And further, of these circumscribed polygons, 
the one that has the greater number of sides has a smaller area than 
the one that has a lesser number; but, on the other hand, the 
isoperimetric polygon that has the greater number of sides is the larger.

\hspace{9cm} -- Galileo Galilei (1638)

\end{document}


To create a triangle there is an information here to pag. 7/13 at link:
https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf
At link https://www.aq-test.com/latex/texmf-dist/tex/generic/shapepar/triangleshapes.def there are some versions of triangles. But you can create one yourself.
% from Gerhard A. Bachmaier (gerhard.bachmaier@meduni-graz.at)
%
% triangle shapes in four orientaions:
% triangleup, triangledown, triangleright, triangleleft.
%  version June 21th, 2006

\def\triangleupshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}t{-10}{20}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}
\def\triangleuppar#1{\Shapepar\triangleupshape $\bigtriangleup$ \ignorespaces #1\par}

\def\triangledownshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{0}t{-10}{20}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}
\def\triangledownpar#1{\Shapepar\triangledownshape #1\unskip\ $\bigtriangledown$\par}

\def\triangleleftshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{8.66}\\%
{0}t{8.66}{0}\\%
{10}t{-8.66}{17.32}\\%
{20}t{8.66}{0}\\%
{20}e{8.66}%
}
\def\triangleleftpar#1{\Shapepar\triangleleftshape 
  $\triangleleft$ \ignorespaces #1\unskip\ $\triangleleft$\par}

\def\trianglerightshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{-8.66}\\%
{0}t{-8.66}{0}\\%
{10}t{-8.66}{17.32}\\%
{20}t{-8.66}{0}\\%
{20}e{-8.66}%
}
\def\trianglerightpar#1{\Shapepar\trianglerightshape 
   $\triangleright$ \ignorespaces #1\unskip\ $\triangleright$\par}

Addendum 1##
After the comment you can define the circle yourself to obtain the exact circle or triangle. Taking the defined \triangleupshape, you will have
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\def\triangleupshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}t{-10}{20}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}
\def\triangleuppar#1{\Shapepar\triangleupshape $\bigtriangleup$ \ignorespaces #1\par}
\begin{document}
\shapepar[.5cm]{\triangleupshape}
I turn, in the following treatises, to various uses of those
    triangles whose generator is unity. But I leave out many more
    than I include; it is extraordinary how fertile in properties
    this triangle is. Everyone can try his hand.

\hspace{9cm} --- Blaise Pascal (1654)

\end{document}


The difficulty is describe exactly the values of the triangle that reproduce the circle done from Donald Knuth:
    {0}%
    {0}b{0}\\%
    {8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
    {17.32}t{-10}{20}\\%
    {17.32}e{0}%

In this link (or this) you can bypass the problem using a patch with a old program that I used to draw any pictures. See also the excellent answer of @Werner: Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text).
This file describes how to install and use the shapepar output driver for the XWindow drawing program XFig. The current version is 3.2.4-shape-1.1. Don't use 3.2.4-shape-1, it has two bad bugs. The naming scheme is first the XFig/Transfig version, appended shape, then the version of the patch.
In this case you draw a triangle and put the text into it. You will have the same result of the textbook of Donald Knuth.
Addendum 2
If you not can use XFig there is another .jar (Java) software named Flowframtk that you can found here: https://github.com/nlct/flowframtk?tab=readme-ov-file. After you can configure this java software https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/texconfig.shtml to create circles and triangles:


Thanks! Unfortunately, that shapepar example only reproduces Knuth's results approximately, not exactly. As specified in the question, I am trying to reproduce them exactly, down to the exact widths and set of breakpoints from Digital Typography. I also couldn't get the triangle shapes to work, either.

@BasilCrow I hope that this addendum can help you to reproduce the circle and the triangle exaclty like you want.
